# Reading XML using C# is this the proper approach?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have a project where i read XML that was exported from another system. The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><xmlimexport>
    <companydata/>
    <articles/>
    <customers/>
    <suppliers/>
    <orders>
        <order>
            <atOrder>
                <OOI_HEAD_DOCUMENT_NUMBER>12345</OOI_HEAD_DOCUMENT_NUMBER>
                **... more rows ...**                       
            </atOrder>
            <rows>
                <row><OOI_ROW_ARTICLE_NUMBER>12345</OOI_ROW_ARTICLE_NUMBER><OOI_ROW_ARTICLE_TEXT>SuperDuperArticleName</OOI_ROW_TEXT>**... more data...**</row>
            </rows>
        </order>
    </orders>
    <bests/>
    <invoices/>
    <supplierinvoices/>
    <pricelists/>
    <parcels/>
</xmlimexport>
```

So what i do is load the path to the XML file then:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

// Load xml file
doc.Load(xmlFile);

// Read order data
XmlNodeList orderList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("order");

foreach (XmlElement order in orderList)
{
    try
    {
        // Read atOrder data (single node)
        XmlNode atOrder = order.SelectSingleNode("atOrder");

        // Read article data (one or many nodes)
        XmlNodeList articles = order.GetElementsByTagName("row");

        // Create a order
        Order customerOrder = new Order();
```

Then read data with:

```
customerOrder.CUS_ID = Convert.ToInt32(atOrder.SelectSingleNode("OOI_HEAD_DOCUMENT_NUMBER").InnerText);
```

But since it can be both Strings, Booleans, Datetime, Date and INT in those fields i find myself having to use `Convert.` very much, is this the proper way to do this or should i use a different approach?

Answer (score 2):

- you can also generate an XSD and based on an XSD a class to deserialize the XML ([short tutorial here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yojoshi/archive/2011/05/14/xml-serialization-and-deserialization-entity-classes-with-xsd-exe.aspx))
- you can read the XML directly into a DataSet (.ReadXML)

Comment: Yeah but this would make me have to recreate the XSD every time the XML gets another field or row data added to it, which would be no good in this project.

Comment: You don't need to recreate the XSD every time the XML gets another field. Just use it the first time to create the class. After that, just edit the Class.cs directly :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at LinqToXml I think that might help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx